# Whats the running time of a loop that increases exponentially with definite comparator?

Tags: java, loops, time-complexity, big-o

What is the running time in Big-O of this loop:

```
for(int n=100; n <= 60000; n = n * 3){
....inner loop code....
}
```

I think it is O(logn) but i am not sure because it is running a definite amount of times. Starting at 100, and going to 60000 multiplying by 3 each time is a set amount of times being run. Is it O(logn)?

Comment: Intuitively l think it's log-base-3 n, but it's been a long time since I've had to calculate any of these things.

Comment: It's O(1), because there is no variable input.

Comment: The relationship between input and runtime is linear, so O(n) would be correct. The coefficient does not matter in this case.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch The value of `n` is exponentially increasing each loop.  The outer loop is O(log n).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch So the index `n` counts 3, 9, 27, 81, etc., and that's `O(n)`?  I'm not sure but I'd like to see that opinion reconsidered.  He's not counting n+3, it's n*3.

Comment: Isn't it O(1)? It runs for a constant time every time...

Comment: I retract my initial statement. It's O(1). There isn't a dynamic range.

Comment: I think the OP may have just simplified his question a little for SO.  If he means this literally, then yes you have a point.  @chevybow

Comment: @markspace he says in the body of his post " but i am not sure because it is running a definite amount of times" which leads me to believe he means it literally.

Comment: @chevybow Fair 'nuff.

Comment: correct i have not simplified this loop

Comment: _..set amount of times being run_ 
You've answered your question here. If the loop always runs a definite amount of times, the run-time is always a constant.

Comment: So basically that big loop is a big constant `k` in front of whatever other run time you have.  It's this loop x Big-O whatever else you have, but constants like this are normally dropped in Big-O notation.

Comment: I don't think this question should be marked down.  It's a pretty good exercise in reading carefully and thinking carefully.  Even a few experienced programmers got tripped up by the question, so I think it's worth asking and answering.

Comment: Can i get an overall consensus... Its O(1) right?

Comment: Yes, I think it's now obvious that it's `O(1)`.  If you want you can answer your own question and just summarize the comments, I think it's fair to give this question a proper answer.

Comment: Appreciate the help mark!

Comment: Don't forget to mark your answer correct.  (It'll be a couple of days before you can.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct answer is O(1) because the loop runs a definite number of times, in that case its always linear time.

Answer (score 0):

It is not O(log n). As you say, the running time of this loop is constant and not dependent on some variable n. You would use Big-O notation here if the number of the times that the loop runs depends on some parameter that was provided externally (e.g the length of an array or something that this algorithm processes)

Answer (score 0):

The complexity is O(log3 n), assuming the code inside the loop is O(1)

Since you are multiplying by 3 every iteration, the number of times you will be iterating will be roughly `x` where `100 * 3 ^ x = 60000`.

To rearrange the formula in terms of `x`, you get `3^x = 600`, so `x = log3(600)`.

Now I assume `60000` is the input `n` here and you want to find how the time needed changes when you increase this number, you get a log3 relationship.

[image]

Comment: I had the same thought, but I think that smarty Andy Turner skunked us both.

Comment: @markspace If this were a trick question, then yeah, I suppose he's right.

Comment: Even if it's not a trick question, you generally don't write log_3 inside of O, since log_3(n) is the same as log(n)/log(3) and 1/log(3) is a constant.

Comment: @ChaiT.Rex that’s very true.